# Microsoft Cognitive Services Vision API: Sending multipart data

Tags: c#, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to call the Microsoft Cognitive API by passing multiple images as per documentation and using the `multipart/form-data`, but I am getting an error that says "Unsupported Media Type". I have tried to use both `ByteArray` and `StreamContent`.

[Api documentation](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56f91f2d778daf23d8ec6739/operations/56f91f2e778daf14a499e1fc).

```
private static byte[] GetImageAsByteArray(Stream fileStream)
{
    using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(fileStream))
    {
        return binaryReader.ReadBytes((int)fileStream.Length);
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var uriBase = "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v1.0/recognizeText";
    var subscriptionKey = "<subscriptionKey>";
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var uri = string.Concat(uriBase, "?", "language=en&detectOrientation=true");
    var images = new List<Stream>();
    var img = Image.FromStream(File.Open("<imageName>", FileMode.Open));
    var stream = new MemoryStream();

    img.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Bmp);
    stream.Position = 0;

    images.Add(stream);

    using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
    {
        foreach (var image in images)
        {
            //content.Add(new StreamContent(stream));
            content.Add(new ByteArrayContent(GetImageAsByteArray(image)));
        }

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", subscriptionKey);
        content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("multipart/form-data");

        var response = client.PostAsync(uri, content).Result;
    }
}
```

Comment: `passing multiple images as per documentation`? the api docs don't say that you can pass in multiple images...

Comment: Thank you for your response but doesn't multipart/form-data used for uploading multiple values in this case images? Maybe that's a bad assumption on my part but why would they support multipart/form-data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to call the Microsoft Cognitive API by **passing multiple images as per documentation and using the multipart/form-data**, but I am getting an error that says "Unsupported Media Type".

```
It is not possible to send multiple images, regardless of header.
```

Please refer to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/vision-api-how-to-topics/howtocallvisionapi) Step 2, it mentions:

> The basic way to perform the Computer Vision API call is by uploading an image directly. This is done by sending a **"POST"** request with **application/octet-stream** content type together with the data read from the **image**.

Example code can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/quickstarts/csharp#analyze-an-image-with-computer-vision-api-using-c-a-nameanalyzeimage-a)

Test environment [here](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56f91f2d778daf23d8ec6739/operations/56f91f2e778daf14a499e1fa).
Notice regardless of header, it is still sending 1 image.
The limits also mention a single image.

Comment: Thank you for our answer but I have already got it to work with sending one image. I am more interested in how to use the multipart/form-data:


'    // This example uses content type "application/octet-stream".
    // The other content types you can use are "application/json" and "multipart/form-data".'

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Matters are murkier in part because some Microsoft Cognitive Services API methods accept multipart MIME, whereas others do not.  For example `/ocr` does but `/recognizeText` does not.  Note also that none of the methods that support multipart MIME will process anything thing other that first part, there is no support for processing multiple images in a single request.